what vertices are parented to an object
is it possible to find out what vertices an object is parented to?
I have an object that needs to bend for an animation I'm making, I also have some simple eyes that I would like to attach to my model. I attached one eye to the model by parenting it to 3 of the vertices on it and am now trying to do the same thing on the other side with the other eye but can't remember what vertices I use for the first eye.

You can do it by running this script in your text editor. Change the name after the brackets for the D.objects['Child'], D.objects['Parent']to match your respective objects.
import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C


# function to find what verts our object is parented to
def set_parent_verts_to_selected(child, parent):
    mesh = parent.data 
    # check that the object is even parented to verts
    if "VERTEX" not in child.parent_type:
        print("Child is not parented to verts.")
        return 
# get the indices of the verts the object is parented to
    p_verts = child.parent_vertices[:]
    for vert in mesh.vertices:
        is_parent = vert.index in p_verts
        vert.select = is_parent
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
    # mesh the object is parented to
    parent = D.objects['Parent']
    # object that is parented to the verts
    child = D.objects['Child']
    set_parent_verts_to_selected(child, parent)
    

